# Unable to import Delaunay from scipy.spatial

Tags: python, windows, import, scipy

I am trying to tesselate a large set of points using Delaunay triangulation. I remember having done this before, but right now, I am about to throw a hissy fit:

- I am running Python 3.6.1 on Windows (Windows is a requirement). I have tried both amd64 and x86 builds direct from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) as well as 
  [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
- I have installed Numpy 1.12 and SciPy 0.19 from Cristoph Gohlke's collection of prebuilt packages [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Both install fine using pip and work well. Except ...

Using Delaunay is a simple matter of feeding some points to scipy.spatial.Delaunay and getting some triangles in return. BUT: the import does not exist even though all the documentation [says it should](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay). I want to be able to do the same thing that happens in the documentation:

```
>>> points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
>>> from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
>>> tri = Delaunay(points)
```

... except in 3D. But without the import, this is not going to happen. My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

measurements = np.array([[x_0, y_0, z_0], [x_1, y_1, z_1], ...])
triangles = Delaunay(measurements)
```

where x_0, y_0 and so on are actually a set of 3D points (filtered measurement data). But it simply does not work at all because the Delaunay import is not available, even though other parts of the scipy.spatial package like KDTree are. The error I am getting is just a pretty generic

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Delaunay'
```

So - the question is: am I having a malfunction or has something changed that I don't get? How do I actually get the Delaunay import?

Comment: Please clarify the problem description *import does not exist* does not mean anything. I could freely interpret this as *you did not put the import line into your code*. I assume you actually tried to import something. What was the exact code you used and what happened (crash, exact error message, etc..)?

Comment: I added some more details. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Do you get an error message or how do you know that it does not work?

Comment: added the error message.

Comment: Does this work: `from scipy.spatial.qhull import Delaunay`?

Comment: Btw, just to be sure, check if `scipy.__version__` is `'0.9'` or higher.

Comment: Yes! That does work. So the package name must have changed I guess. Also, the version I am using is 0.19, so I am good on that one. Thanks :-)

Comment: Interesting. I have 0.19 too (from the same source) and `from scipy.spatial import Delaunay` works although it is just an alias for `qhull.Delaunay`.

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu just for testing - and the scipy.spatial.Delaunay import works. But on my Windows machine, only qhull.Delaunay works. At this point, I am pretty sure it is an oddity in my setup,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/__init__.py#L95) is an alias for [`scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx#L1693). If the import is broken for some reason, importing the latter directly may work in some cases:

```
from scipy.spatial.qhull import Delaunay
```